# Unix grep command trying to find a speific word in story

Tags: unix, grep

I am trying to find a specific word in a story "und" but it cannot have e after this word, here is an example:

```
Under the rope she went. Going under the rope she ran towards the abandoned 
house and and went around it to find her sister.
 She bound over a fallen tree while running around the house, and it was there she found her sister. 
She now understood where her sister had been going all this time. 
It was not until now, every time her sister went missing for a few hours, she never knew where she went.
```

with the grep command I need to find the words: around, bound, and found, but not: understood, under, rounded, etc.
I have tried:

```
grep 'und' story.txt | grep -v 'unde'
```

but for some reason from the first part of this code I would end up with it also highlighting the word "until" as well, but I need it to have the "und" not just "un", any advice?

Comment: do you need to extract those words or simply get lines with those words?

Comment: What about `grep -w 'und' story.txt`? Or perhaps `grep 'und[^e]' story.txt`?

Comment: `grep 'und' story.txt | grep -v 'unde'` should work actually... and shouldn't match words like `until`.. something else seems problematic here

Comment: `und` with no following `e` is surely `und[^e]`?

Comment: @MarkSetchell wont work for words like `found` at end of line.. and OP needs to clarify what to do for words like `underground`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this one ?

```
grep -oi '[^ ]*und\>' file
```

Output:

```
$ grep -oi '[^ ]*und\>' file
around
bound
around
found
```